# Setting backreference automagically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, aop

I am developping a Java EE application with **Spring**, **JPA**, **Hibernate**.

In our business model, we have several back references, either OneToMany or OneToOne.
We need it for processing purpose.

We end up having many setters that handle backreference automatically :

```
class Dog {

    @OneToOne
    private DogOwner owner;

    public void setOwner(DogOwner owner) {
       this.owner = owner;
       if (!this.owner.getDog().equal(this)) {
          owner.setDog(this);
       }
    }

    [...]
 }

class DogOwner {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="owner")
    private Dog dog;

    public void setDog(Dog dog) {
       this.dog = dog;
       if (!this.dog.getOwner().equal(this)) {
          dog.setOwner(this)
       }
    }

    [...]
 }
```

Same thing for **OneToMany** associations and `add()` methods on the sets/lists.

This works but is a bit tedious and error prone to write those automatic setters for all back references.

Since **JPA** has all the required annotations and with the power of Spring / OAP, is there some configuration or piece of framwork that can handle that automatically ?

**Edit : Example**

To clarify, I would like that back references stay coherent automatically in my model, even before doing a "persist".

Here is the behavior I want :

```
Dog rex = new Dog();
Dog mirza = new Dog();
DogOwner bob = new DogOwner();

bob.setDog(rex);
assert(rex.getOwner() == bob);

bob.setDog(mirza);
assert(rex.getOwner() == null);
assert(mirza.getOwner() == bob);
```

If not, I think I am about to write my own.

Comment: I am missing your question. what is your target?

Comment: You know that technically you don't have to modify the non-owning side (the one with `mappedBy`)? Only the owning side is used.

Comment: @CycDemo, see the example in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the inverse relp is working properly.
Could try this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", unique= true, nullable=true, insertable=true, updatable=true)
private DogOwner owner;
```

Thats going by this:
JPA/OneToOneMappingBidirectional.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355_JPA/OneToOneMappingBidirectional.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so to make back-reference automatically. I use `overload constructor` for that, base on my experience.

Example

```
public class DogOwner {
    private Dog dog;

    public DogOwner () {
    }

    public DogOwner (Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
        dog.setDogOwner(this);
    }
    //getter and setter
}

public class Dog {
    private DogOwner dogOwner;

    public Dog() {
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

If so, you can reduce the initilizaion code as below;

```
Dog d = new Dog();
DogOwner owner = new DogOwner(d);
```